# Shnayim Veshiv'im Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred seventy-two?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avaraham recognized his Creator for 172 years.

[[Nedarim 32a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=16&daf=32&format=pdf)  learns that Avraham recognized Hashem at 3 years old from the pasuk עֵקֶב אֲשֶׁר-שָׁמַע אַבְרָהָם בְּקֹלִי - *Since Avraham listened to My voice.  The gematria of Ekev= 172.  So: For 172 years Avaraham listened to My voice.  Avraham died at 175.  175-172=3]

*The exact meaning of עֵקֶב is debated

Comment: ..." "Since" is in Hebrew "aikev" = ayin (70) + kuf (100) + vais (2) = 172 -- implying that Abraham hearkened to G-d for 172 years.

Answer (score 3):

In this weeks parashas Yisro, there are 172 words in the Aseres haDibros. (Count 'em.)

Answer (score 1):

On a year with only 1 Adar and Chesvon 29 days / Kislev 30 days we say Mashiv HaRuach for 172 days

Answer (score 0):

172 years after the USA declared its independence, the State of Israel was established.

1948 - 1776 = 172